# Transpose multiple rows into columns with unique ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose, array-formulas, vba

new to all this and I need some help on what I assume is transposing data - multiple rows into unique columns with values against each id

[Here's my current data set:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEP6Y.png)

[I need to get the data into this format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gelEq.png)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: That's not quite 'transposing'. I'd call that 'pivoting'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us what you have tried.  And also **please** read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your example does not allow for anyone to easily help you.  Have you ever tried to place a screen shot into an Excel Worksheet?  It's a lot of work to expect from those who are donating their time.

Comment: @NiteshHalai only manually moving the data so far but it's such a pain.

Comment: @CLR Sorry, you're right it is pivoting - any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you want to Pivot your original data. This is a feature of Excel. If you want this to be automated in VBA, record yourself inserting a Pivot and check the code the recorder has created.

Answer (score 0):

1.Select any cell within your original table.

2. Go to insert tab and select Pivot table. Make sure that the range is your full table and ideally select the option to create it on a new worksheet.
3. Enter SKU as your row labels, attribute as the colmn label, and value as the value. It should bring sum of values, but you can change if that is not the case.